# How to process Laravel Resources inside Another resource?

Tags: laravel, api, resources, lumen

I have Resources inside resources, normally it would work just fine but if a Resource 1.1.1 inside the a Resource 1.1 give a field with a certain value i need it to return empty array at Resource 1. In order for it not to show that specific Resource 1.1 inside the collection Resource 1

Tried using json_decode and it forced the Resource to process and gives a string of result of the Resource and json_decode to return it back to array.

//Resource 1.1->

```
    return [
        'id' => (int)$this->id,
        'block' => BlockResource::collection($this->blocks)->data($this->parameters);
    ];
```

//(1.1.1) BlockResource

```
 return [
        'id' => (int)$this->id,
        'groups' => Resource::collection()
    ];
```

dd($BlockResource); //shows Resource object not the processed result

$BlockResource = json_encode($BlockResource);

dd($BlockResource); //string with the processed and can do json_decode to return as array....

Example :

```
resource1: [
                {
                    id : 1
                    block:{
                      id : 1
                      groups : [1,2,3,4,5]
                    }
                },
                {
                    id : 2
                    block:{
                      id : 2
                      groups : []
                    }
                }
]
```

The 2º resource1.1 should not show since groups is an empty array
I can use json_encode/decode trick but it would give me excess processing.

Any ideas :D?

Answer (score 0):

Well decided to go into JsonResource methods and

```
/**
 * Resolve the resource to an array.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request|null  $request
 * @return array
 */
public function resolve($request = null)
```

works for me